# Nested class of an instance is null

Tags: c#

Upd.

This is a bug of my IDE. Text saving was not working.

Moral: IDE can fail too.

The issue is irrelevant now and can be closed.

---

When I instantiate the VehicleData class, it is not null (as it should be). When I create an instance of the GameData class, which specifies that a new instance of VehicleData `... = new VehicleData();` needs to be created, it is not created, but is null. Why does this happens? Even if you write it into the constructor, nothing will change.

Have a look at the pictures.

[Debug | Instance of GameData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfSsS.png)

[Debug | Instance of VehicleData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKNrX.png)

```cs
public class GameData
{
    public int Stars { get; set; } = 0;

    public VehicleData VehicleData { get; set; } = new VehicleData();
}
```

The only way to do what I want

```cs
var example = new GameData();
example.VehicleData = new VehicleData();
```

This will be overcomplicated soon, so I want to instantiate all nested classes (one for now) by only instantiating the root class like this `var example = new GameData();`.

Comment: Your code, as provided in the question, works fine for me. You need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue for us to be able to help you.

Comment: You did well, what's the problem?

Comment: Please look at the picture 'Debug | Instance of GameData'. It shows that VehicleData property inside of instance of GameData is null. It should not be null.

Comment: @KinG - Yes, I looked at the image. It shows a different behaviour than your code. That's why you need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. Can you please do that?

Comment: I'm in confusion right now. I tried to reproduce my own issue in a new C# project but everything works as it should be https://imgur.com/zdHD6gV. I'll try to examine it a bit deeply so I can provide relevant info about the issue.

Comment: Works fine [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sz5WCI). could you provide an example, something like this one.

Comment: @Enigmativity Oh, okay. I'll do.

Comment: My environment is Unity 2019.4.8f1. Code was in MonoBehaviour component's Awake() method. I thought it was kind of a bug of Unity or my dullness. But at some point I realized that saving in Visual Studio is no longer working. ' = new VehicleData();' was in my IDE but not in the file. The save button just does nothing. Probably I found a bug of Visual Studio IDE because I had this saving issue when I left my computer turned on for 8+ hours. Thank you for your advice and help, and I ask you to forgive the time spent.

Comment: @KinG - All good. We're here to help. I'm glad you solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced your classes in a Console apps(.NetCore and .NetFramework), it work just fine,
Maybe Clean\Rebuild would do.